# Firebase security - newData() as a parameter of hasChildren() expression

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I want allow users to create their account only if they have a token(invitation).
In my firebase Security i have:

```
{
"rules": {
  ".read": false,
  ".write": false,
  "users": {
    // allow to write if in the invitations there is child equal to token from newData()
    ".write":"root.child('invitations').hasChild(newData.child('token').val())",  
  },
 "invitations":{
   "$invitation":{
     ".read": "true"
   }
  }
}
```

}

as is in the comment i want allow to write if in the invitations there is child equal to token from newData().

From Simulator:

```
Attempt to write {"token":"evl6yky3vi0pmn29","name":"John"} to /users/99 with auth=null
/:.write: "false"
    => false
/users:.write: "root.child('invitations').hasChild(newData.child('token').val())"
6:52: hasChild() expects a string argument.
    => false
/users/99:<no rules>
```

how should I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've almost got it perfect. The only flaw here is that you're trying to write to users/99, but you've put the rule on users/.

Presumably, you meant this:

```
"users": {
   "$user_id": {
      // allow to write if in the invitations there is child equal to token from newData()
      ".write":"root.child('invitations').hasChild(newData.child('token').val())",  
   }
},
```

Comment: I've used this solution to solve my question; however do rules allow us to use multiple wildcards? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41558719/firebase-security-child-expects-a-string-variable

Comment: Does val() function same as exists() ?

Comment: No, it returns the value. Exists returns a boolean. In this case, we're using the value as a key so exists wouldn't work at all. API refs are your friend here.

Comment: Misinterpreted val as valid until now :). Thank you!

Comment: So,   '.hasChild(newData.child('token').val())' is same as;   .'child(newData.child('token').val()).exists()'