# Firebase Security Rules: Unknown variable $requestId2?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

When user1 --> user2 (user1 sends a request to user2). I am trying to perform certain checks using firebase rules, which are:

1. Check if username2 exists
2. Check if both users are not already friends

for that I've written the following rule:

```
{
  "rules": 
  {
    "requests":
    {
      "$requestId":
      {
        ".read": "auth != null",
        ".write": "auth!=null && 
                   data.child('username2').val() == true &&
                   root.child('usernames-list').child( data.child('username2') ).exists() && 
                   !root.child('user-requests').child( auth.uId ).child('accepted-pending').child($requestId2).child( data.child('username2') ).exists()"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But it returns the following errors at two areas:

1. data.child('username2')   ----> Line 9: child() expects a string argument.
2. data.child($requestId2)   ----> Line 9: Unknown variable $requestId2

Data Structure:

```
requests
---$requestId
    ---key: value

user-requests
---$userId
    ---pending
        ---$requestId               
            ---key: value
    ---accepted
        ---$requestId
            ---key: value
    ---rejected
        ---$requestId
            ---key: value
    ---unfriend
        ---$requestId
            ---key: value
    ---accepted-pending
        ---$requestId               
            ---key: value
```

Incoming json:

```
user1       --> authId of user1
username1   --> username of 1st user
username2   --> username of 2nd user
...
```

Note 1: I've tried using `newData.` instead of `data.` and still get the same errors. Also, `newData('username2').isString()` also returns the same error

Note 2: I could avoid the `$requestId2` (error) by making a separate list only containing the usernames that user1 is friends with and compare it against that; but I'd still need to be able to use `data.('username2')` as a field withing the `root.child()`

Edit 1: The following rule publishes successfully, however I'm not sure if it still does what I've mentioned (need to check) :

```
".write": "auth!=null && 
           newData.child('username2').val() == true &&
           root.child('usernames-list').hasChild( newData.child('username2').val() ) && 
           !root.child('user-requests').child( auth.uId ).child('accepted-pending-usernames').hasChild( data.child('username2').val() )"
```

Ref:[Firebase security - newData() as a parameter of hasChildren() expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20472583/firebase-security-newdata-as-a-parameter-of-haschildren-expression)

Comment: `s/auth.uId/auth.uid/g` (in words: replace `auth.uId` with `auth.uid`) to get rid of the first error message. JavaScript is case-sensitive and `auth.uId` <> `auth.uid`.

Comment: Replace `$requestId2` with `$requestId` to get rid of the second error message.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen But '$requestId' and '$requestId2 'need not always be the same. Hence, it was more like '$wildcard1' and '$wildcard2'

Answer (score 1):

Edit 2: This should be the solution:

1. `.val()` has been added within the brackets
2. `.exists()` remains at the end
3. I've created a separate list of usernames (`/accepted-pending-usernames/`) to overcome the wildcard error
4. `data` has been replaced with `newData`

   ```
   ".write":  "auth!=null && 
               newData.child('username2').val() == true && 
               root.child('usernames-list').child( newData.child('username2').val() ).exists() && 
               !root.child('user-requests').child( auth.uId ).child('accepted-pending').child('accepted-pending-usernames').child( data.child('username2').val() ).exists()"
   ```

**Note:** Question may still remain unsolved as its unclear if firebase allows one to use multiple wildcards in the rules